# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android

Recently I sometimes got this exception when MainActivity called onResume().

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.qau4d.c35s3.androidapp/com.xxx.XXX.XXX.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3400)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1510)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1687)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.isTopOfTask(ActivityManagerNative.java:5475)
at android.app.Activity.isTopOfTask(Activity.java:5961)
at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1252)
at com.qau4d.c35s3.androidapp.onResume(XActivity.java:29)
at com.qau4d.c35s3.androidapp.onResume(MainActivity.java:196)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6768)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
```

Both in `MainActivity` and super class `XActivity`, only `super.onResume();` is called. It's really strange to get this exception after a long time normal development.I checked some relative reference material but nothing got.

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: @Keyson Chous, post the code what are you performing in `onResume()`

Comment: What is the android sdk version you are using? ever since it was working normal, what changes have you done on the project structure (Like ui theme)?

Comment: Got the same error from users. Happening only on Android 7.1.1. The app  is compiled with SDK 25, AppCompat v7 25.3.0.

Comment: Any solutions? Same problem

Comment: got it on 7.0 Samsung S6 Edge

Comment: Same problem here, report from API 24, 25. The exception is thrown from `super.onResume()`.

Comment: I've got same problem. Any solution available?

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you doesn't post source code. Please share some source code and we gonna help you.

Comment: Any update on this, anyone?

Comment: Were you able to figure out a reproduction steps for this problem? I guess this would be useful...

Comment: Anyone able to fix this issue? I am facing it in my new app.

Comment: Google issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66849632

Comment: @user1269737  your answewa should be accepted one, because it is a bug in support library. I would give you +1 if I could for this

Comment: got it on Samsung Galaxy S8 (dreamqltesq), Android 9

Comment: Any updates? Got it on Hisense 430, Android 9

Answer (score 10):

In the method Activity#isTopOfTask we can see:

```
private boolean isTopOfTask() {
    if (mToken == null || mWindow == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        return ActivityManager.getService().isTopOfTask(getActivityToken());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in ActivityManagerService#isTopOfTask we can found:

```
@Override
public boolean isTopOfTask(IBinder token) {
    synchronized (this) {
        ActivityRecord r = ActivityRecord.isInStackLocked(token);
        if (r == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return r.task.getTopActivity() == r;
    }
}
```

So, I think that ActivityRecord is null.But I don't know why it is null....

Comment: what is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 5):

There is insufficient information in your question to determine the cause of the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`,  Unfortunately the android `ActivityThread` doesn't log the stacktrace of that exception, and the exception message appears to be empty.

However, it looks like there is a way forward.  The exception is handled by the following code in the `ActivityThread::performResumeActivity` method:

```
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!mInstrumentation.onException(r.activity, e)) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to resume activity "
                    + r.intent.getComponent().toShortString()
                    + ": " + e.toString(), e);
            }
        }
```

If you register an `Instrumentation` class for your activity, it should be possible to use an `onException` method to log the stacktrace for the causal exception.  Another possibility is to use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set a handler for the thread in  which the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

These won't solve the problem (!) but it will get you a step closer to a solution.